# Calculate business days between two dates

Tags: formula, date

I'm trying to create a formula that would calculate the business days between "Claim Filled/Submitted Date" and "Date/Time Closed" for claims turn time. I'm using the formula:

```
(5 * ( FLOOR( ( date_1 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( date_1 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )
-
(5 * ( FLOOR( ( date_2 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( date_2 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )
```

However, I'm not sure how to replace date_1 and date_2 with the fields I want. I keep getting an error saying the custom field doesn't exist.

Comment: Which object are you trying to create the formula on? Which fields?

Comment: The fields are the "Claim Filled/Submitted Date" and "Date/Time Closed" for Cases. I'm creating the formula for a summary report since I don't have access to the Formula Editor.

Comment: Do you have the API names of the fields? Is Date/Time Closed the standard ClosedDate field? Unless it is a standard field that has been renamed 'Claim Filled/Submitted Date' seems to be a custom field. Can you show an example of what you tried?

Comment: The API name of the Date/Time Closed is the standard ClosedDate field. The "Claim Filed/Submitted Date" is a custom field with API: Claim_Filed_Date__c

Comment: Here's an example of what I've tried: 

`(5 * ( FLOOR( ( ClosedDate - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( ClosedDate - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )
-
(5 * ( FLOOR( ( Claim_Filed_Date__c - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( Claim_Filed_Date__c - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )`

Comment: If you're using `ClosedDate` from the `Case` Object, that's a Date-Time field and you'll need to get the DateValue of it. That's likely why it's not working for you.

Comment: Even after trying to find the DateValue of it, the same error occurs: Field ClosedDate does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that you are doing this as a formula for a summary report, instead of as a field on Case. Formulas in a summary report are for formulating a result based on aggregate values rather than per row. So for example you can use the Sum, Min, Max, or Average of a field value, instead of referencing the field itself.

If you want to do the formula you have entered then you will need to do it as a formula type field on the Case object. You should be able to use the formula you have referenced with some minor adjustments. Assuming that Claim_Filed_Date__c is a date field, this should work:

```
(5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE(ClosedDate) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) 
    + MIN( 5, MOD( DATEVALUE(ClosedDate) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 )  ) 
) - 
(5 * FLOOR( ( Claim_Filed_Date__c - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) 
      + MIN( 5, MOD( Claim_Filed_Date__c - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) 
)
```